# What bignum libraries work with D?

Tags: d, biginteger

I'm in need of a bignum library for representing large integers. What options do I have with the D programming language? Are there, for instance, GMP bindings?

Update:

I'm trying to use the inbuilt BigInt as described below but it appears it's not available with the GDC.

```
import std.bigint;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
  BigInt n = "123";
  writefln(n);
}
```

When I try to compile this code with `gdc main.d` I'm told it can't find bigint.d. Does gdc only implement some of the library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you sure you use a D2 version of gdc?

Comment: If you didn't compile GDC yourself, then you probably aren't using the latest version of D.

Comment: As I understand it, GDC has all of Phobos with it, but I've never actually used it myself, so I don't know. Its current homepage is here: https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/wiki/Home

Answer (score 5):

If what you're looking for is a big integer type, then there's [`BigInt`](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_bigint.html#BigInt) in the standard library. On the other hand, if you're specifically looking to use GMP, then all you have to do is have `extern(C)` declarations for the appropriate types and functions in GMP that you need, and you can call them directly from D. Check out out [this page](http://www.d-programming-language.org/interfaceToC.html) for more details on how to use C code in D.

Comment: btw, an MPFR binding is included in dil:
https://github.com/azizk/dil/blob/master/src/util/mpfr.d

Answer (score 4):

Paul Anderson is working on a BigFloat abstraction for the standard library.